# jupyter notebook "kernel starting, pleasing wait" on server

Tags: ubuntu, server, jupyter

the server is on a ubuntu and I tried to use the server's jupyter on my Mac. The jupyter worked and I can see files, but when I tried to run code, the code got stuck and never moved on.

I tried jupyter on Ubuntu directly, and it worked quite well on the server.

But when I try to use jupyter on my Mac, it got stuck and read "kernel starting, please wait"

anyone knows why? thank you